# Opening mdb files in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-rec, microsoft-access

I have an MDB document that I need to view on my Ubuntu machine, I downloaded MDB viewer and when opening the file with it the application closes. Also OpenOffice DB viewer does not want to work.

Are there any other applications that I can use?

Comment: What MDB viewer have you downloaded? How was it packaged?

Comment: .deb packaged, it's called MDB Viewer

Comment: This question has zilch to do with Microsoft Access. You're not even using the Microsoft Jet/ACE database engine. The Access tag is not going to get you better answers on this, because the only people who will know the answer are those who use MDB files *without* Access.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you'd better install the mdbtools-gmdb (http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/mdbtools-gmdb) through Ubuntu package manager, otherwise there are no guarantees that the package is binary compatible. (Lots of distros use .deb)

Comment: Getting the Following Error, when trying to install mdbtools-gmdb

Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.17.0)

Comment: How are you doing the installation?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get mdbtools-gmdb`

Comment: Gives me E: Invalid operation mdbtools-gmdb

Comment: Maybe an `apt-cache search mdbtools` to see if you can see it under a slightly different name?

Comment: Oops, of course `sudo apt-get install mdbtools-gmdb`. Has been a long time since I had used Debian.

Comment: Sorry man, I somehow didn't see install was missing

Comment: It installed, but still can't open the file

Comment: Can open the file with OpenOffice Database viewer but it looks scrambled

Answer (score 18):

Re: Installing mdbtools, line should be:

```
sudo apt-get install mdbtools-gmdb
```

That's why you go the 'Invalid operation...' error.

(can't comment yet, hence the separate answer)

Comment: Now you should be able to commment.

Comment: @Macha Only on my own, need 50 to comment. I'm not a power stackoverflow user, but I got enough rep to do stuff. I came over here and I can't do *anything*. :-) It'll just take some time...

Comment: @Tim Lytle: transfer your profile info from stackoverflow.com. This should give you some point boost!

Comment: @EFraim - at the risk of getting in trouble for 'site' discussions: I have associated my stackoverflow profile with all the other sites, but that didn't change my points. Or did you just mean your upvote would give me some points? Thanks either way.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/). It has "MS Access (UCanAccess)" driver to open .mdb files.

To [install](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-dbeaver-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/):

```
wget https://dbeaver.io/files/dbeaver-ce_latest_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i dbeaver-ce_latest_amd64.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

Then connect to the .mdb file:

[image: screenshot]

Tested on version 21.0.0

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 18.04 I tried installing `mdbtools-gmdb` but it couldn't find the package. I ended up installing `mdbtools` with `apt install mdbtools`.

This [package provides libraries](http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/install/c42.htm) to connect to `mdb` files as well as [command line utilities](http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/install/x53.htm) including `mdb-tables`, `mdb-export`, `mdb-sql`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to view or export the contained data you also could use an online viewer/exporter like [www.mdbopener.com](http://www.mdbopener.com).

mdbopener.com is using the mdbtools for .mdb files and the jackcess library (java) for .accdb files. Disclosure: I am the creator of www.mdbopener.com

Comment: Still works in Apr. 2022, some 6.5 years later.  Accepts a direct URL too, so no need to download and re-upload, at least for publicly-available files.  Returns CSV and XLS.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cloud version of MS Access available. (http://www.apponfly.com/en/micro...)

They provide 30day free trial via remote desktop connection.