# How can I view a 200 gb mdb file in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, microsoft-access, database, mdb

I have a 200 GB mdb file and I need to view the contents in Ubuntu 16.04. What is the best way to do this? I've tried using mdbtools as [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/34326/opening-mdb-files-in-ubuntu) says, but I'm not really sure how to view the contents of the mdb file with it, I try to open the file and nothing happens.

Thank You.

Comment: Surely you mean 200 **MB**

Comment: @misha256 nope, 200GB

Comment: The maximum size for a JET database file, which is what Microsoft Access uses (known to most of the world as `.mdb` files) is 2GB.  If your file is actually 200GB, then it has to be some other type of file that someone has renamed with an .mdb extension.

Comment: Do you mean *mdf*, a MSSQL Server database format?

Comment: @hex no, it was created with the lmdb python module

Comment: Could you explain how you create a 200GB file using the lmdb python module? @Matt